# knockout: Trouble removing a newly added item

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to learn how to use KnockOut... never have before and I've been thrown into the fire on a site already using it. Everything here works fine:

```
        function MasterViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.Supervisors = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Supervisors)));

            self.AddSupervisor = function(request) {
                var request = new Supervisor({
                    FullName:  $('#SupervisorId option:selected').text(),
                    SupervisorId: $('#SupervisorId option:selected').val()
                });
                self.Supervisors.push(request);
                // do server side call here
            }

            self.RemoveSupervisor = function(request) {
                if (request.SupervisorID() > 0)
                {
                    self.Supervisors.remove(request);
                     // do server side call here
                }
            }
        }
```

Well.  Everything almost works fine:

- The initial data from the server loads and displays perfectly
- I can remove existing items (that came from the server on the original page load)
- I can add new items

But, when I try to remove an item that I just added, I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: request.SupervisorID is not a function

[image]

`SupervisorId` is a dropdown.  The `AddSupervisor` call is made from a button.  I can show the HTML if needed. Also, although I may not need this `if`:

```
if (request.SupervisorID() > 0)
```

Even without it, I am going to need the ID of the supervisor that was added.

Comment: What is the value of "request" inside the function? The Html would indeed be helpful. I'd like to see what the binding looks like where RemoveSupervisor is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the server side isn't case-sensitive, and is loading data with `SupervisorID`.  When you add a new one, you're creating it with `SupervisorId` (lowercase `d`).  The server must be accepting of that.  JavaScript isn't.

You need to either change the newly created users to use `SupervisorID`, or have the `RemoveSupervisor` function use `SupervisorId` - whichever change makes more sense in your overall structure.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. He said that he can removes existing items.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Yes - ones loaded from the server, that probably have the correct casing in the property/function name.  The ones added locally in JS cannot be removed, because the casing doesn't match.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the problem either.  But it's worth trying and testing! And, I really should be consistent with the casing anyway. BRB.

Comment: Yup!  That did it!!

Comment: Ok, I will watch for the edit.  The problem I described in the OP is solved, but if you see something else, I'm very happy to listen.

Comment: @Casey No if it's worked then the other thing isn't an issue anyway - depends on what's going on inside the `Supervisor` constructor, I misread what was going on there.